# Does TinyMCE 6 Open Source count editor loads?

Tags: tinymce

I was reading that TinyMCE is Open Source, however, on the website it says that the "Core" (Free) version is limited by 1000 editor loads.

We did the installation with NPM, to be completely self-hosted, but we saw again on the TinyMCE website that the "Core" version does not allow this.

Is the Core version the same as the Open Source?

Comment: We're having the same confusion.  did this get resolved?

Comment: @SriramR Unfortunately their documentation is very confusing.
In some places they say there is a limit and others do not.
When we contacted them they didn't answer the question.
They asked how many client companies of ours would have access to use TinyMCE and based on that they set an annual price for the company.

We decided to opt out of using TinyMCE and opted for Froala instead. Froala's licensing model seems to us to be simpler and more direct.
Just buy the license and use it.

Comment: The latest info from TinyMCE as of July 2023 is that the open-source Cloud version has limitation on Editor loads while the self hosted one doesn't.

Comment: Because the self-hosted version is the Open Source Community version which looks is under an MIT license it would be a big surprise if there were a 1000 load limit. I have contacted them to clarify because I think it is confusing. I update here if I get an answer from them.

Comment: As a follow up on my previous comment. TinyMCE confirmed that there is no 1000 load limit for the self hosted version.

Answer (score 2):

The latest info from TinyMCE as of July 2023 is that the open-source Cloud version has limitation on Editor loads while the self hosted one doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, they benefit from the confusing message.  If a dev thinks they are only limited to 1000 loads and convinces the client to pay for it, it's a win for TinyMCE.  The misaligned incentives create this.